# Filter out items in a JSON object based on another list

Tags: python, json

I have a json file similar to this

```
filename = 'data.json'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

`data.json`

```
    [{
        "id":"1",
        "url":"http://",
        "Types:["online","offline" ],
        "content:[{
        "Title":"A long title"
        "body":"A long body"
        }],
        "Other":"other1"


    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "url":"http://2",
        "Types:["online2","offline"2 ],
        "content:[{
        "Title":"A long title2"
        "body":"A long body2"
        }],
        "Other":"other2"


    },
    .
    .
    .
    {
        "id":"2000",
        "url":"http://2000",
        "Types:["online2","offline2000" ],
        "content:[{
        "Title":"A long title200"
        "body":"A long body200"
        }],
        "Other":"other2000"


    }]
```

I want to create a new json file if **id** in the original matches my expected **id**s.

For simplesity lets assume I want to create a new json with odd ids of original json:

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "url":"http://",
    "Types:["online","offline" ],
    "content:[{
    "Title":"A long title"
    "body":"A long body"
    }],
    "Other":"other1"


},
{
    "id":"3",
    "url":"http://3",
    "Types:["online2","offline"3 ],
    "content:[{
    "Title":"A long title3"
    "body":"A long body2"
    }],
    "Other":"other3"


},
.
.
.
{
    "id":"1999",
    "url":"http://1999",
    "Types:["online1999","offline1999" ],
    "content:[{
    "Title":"A long title1999"
    "body":"A long body1999"
    }],
    "Other":"other1999"
}]
```

How should I do this?

EDIT

This is how I have tried,I added my preferred IDs in an array.

```
js=[]
for i in data:
    #print i
    if i['id']==arr:
        js.append(i)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: What have you tried? Add your code.

Comment: This is simple. We can help, but we need a couple of things. Where is your ID list? What have you tried?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have edited the question and added my method but it returns empty array

Comment: @Eka That's better. Added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert your `id_list` to a set for quick and efficient lookup:

```
id_set = set(arr)
```

Next, you may use `filter` to retain only those items in your list whose ids match one of those in your list.

```
new_data = list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] in id_set, data))
```

Ensure that your `id_set` elements are strings, because the `id`s in your example are of string type.

Comment: I have his error `KeyError: 'id'` and also can you simplify the code a little bit more. I have only a minimal understanding of filter and lamdas

Comment: @Eka `KeyError: 'id'` means that the data you posted isn't the same as the data you have. What is the name of the key that _actually_ has the ID? `filter` will filter out elements in the list that don't meet the criteria specified by the lambda function.

Comment: I want to apolgize first bcoz I rarely work wit filter and lambda is this correct `lambda x: x['id'] in id_set` my `id_set` has list similar to this `{"1","3","5",...."1999"}` it doesn have and variable "id"

Comment: @Eka I am talking about your `data`. Just print `data[0]` and tell me what it has.

Comment: @Eka Now paste here, the line of code that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("data.json", "r+") as f:        
    original = json.load(f)
    processed = [entry for entry in original if int(entry['id']) % 2 == 1]
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(processed, f)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.